# Pass reference to another activity - Android

Tags: java, android, database

I am very new to android, so I am experimenting with the tutorial code.  In particular, the notepad.

If you look here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex2.html, at **Step 5** they are putting values so that it can be used by NoteEdit.

I would like to pass a reference of NotesDbAdapter into NoteEdit so that I can actually do some entirely different things.

It does not seem to invoke a constructor though.  I have tried adding a paramiter to NoteEdit onCreate, but it does not seem to like this? :-(

I most look forward to hearing your answers, experts! :-D

Comment: Why could you want to do that? Actually, that's discouraged and difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Put/Get extras are not passed via constructors, you have to explicitly read from the intent, probably in the onCreate method

**First Activity**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**New Activity**

code in onCreate

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
myIntent.getExtra("key");
```

If you want to pass custom classes, your class must implement serializable and you then read by:

```
Bundle e = getIntent().getExtras();
Object obj=(Object) e.getSerializable("key");
```

Comment: My "custom" class should implement serializable?

Comment: Would it be better to to the database work in First Activity and pass that in with the intent.

It would need to have two details.  My values from database is like this:

"animal","cat"
"animal","dog"
"food","potato"

Comment: Create a reduced class that stores fields you want to pass, kinda enum type class. This class will implement serializable. Then you put the data into that class on whatever activity or model level you want. You can that pass it to another activity with the intent, and you will read the data as you want. Keep it simple if you need to pass 5 fields, you create a class having 5 members to store the data. Or even simpler you can use the Extras to avoid this step. I don't know how complicate is your result.

Comment: they values are in pairs:

Kind (i.e. Animal or food)

Instance (Cat, potato)

But, cats are never food ;-) lol

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mr. Castiblanco. Do not try to do this.

Your `Adapter` holds a reference to the main `Activity`, the one with the `ListView` that the `Adapter` is attached to. If you were to get your `Adapter` over to the new `Activity`, then your new `Activity` will hold a reference to your old `Activity`. This will prevent Android from being able to destroy your old `Activity` to free up memory for other applications, since your new `Activity` will hold a reference to it, preventing garbage collection.

If you need to share a data model between activities, hold that data model outside of those activities (e.g., database, `Service`, `Application`). Your `Adapter` is not your data model.

Comment: So, I should redeclare the database class and connection in my Edit class?

Comment: OR, as I said in another comment.

Some kind of array map that is passed in the extras?

Comment: "I should redeclare the database class and connection in my Edit class?" That is one approach. "Some kind of array map that is passed in the extras?" As I wrote, if you need to share a data model between activities, hold that data model outside of those activities (e.g., database, Service, Application). Passing your entire data model between activities via extras is not an approach I would recommend.